# unexpected sublist result returned by Hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, sublist

I hava a HQL query as the following which returns a java.util.RandomAccessSubList of ORDER. The offset of the SubList is 1,so the first element of the query result list can't be accessed.

```
SELECT vendor.order FROM OrderVendor vendor WHERE vendor.user.id=? ORDER BY vendor.order.creationTime desc

select order1_.order_id as order1_18_,(..... other fields....) 
from ORDER_VENDOR ordervendo0_ 
inner join ORDER order1_ on ordervendo0_.order_id=order1_.order_id, 
where ordervendo0_.user_id=? 
order by order1_.creationTime desc
```

I tried another way.First get a List of OrderVendor, then use the the method OrderVendor.getOrder() to access the order.But is's a little fussy!

```
FROM OrderVendor vendor WHERE vendor.user.id=? ORDER BY vendor.order.creationTime desc

select ordervendo0_.vendor_id as vendor1_20_ (....other fields...) 
from ORDER_VENDOR ordervendo0_, 
ORDER order2_ 
where ordervendo0_.order_id=order2_.order_id 
and ordervendo0_.user_id=? 
order by order2_.creationTime desc limit ?
```

My question is why the first query return a SubList and Why the offset of the SubList is 1 ?

Thanks !

Geln